# Images inserted into HTML properly but not displayed - size is 0*0px

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, sinatra, haml

I am using a HAML template of a bootstrap carousel to display all images from a folder.

The images should not be displayed with a size of 0 by 0 pixels. There is no CSS property that would be setting this, the width of the element is set to 100% in CSS and even changing the size in a browser console does nothing.

All the images are accessible directly from a browser otherwise (like http://localhost:4567/car-images/fb_1.jpg) and there are no 404 errors.

This is the HAML template with a block of Ruby code:

```
.col-sm-6#carousel
        .carousel.slide#myCarousel{ "data-ride" => "carousel", :style => "height:inherit"}
            %ol.carousel-indicators
            .carousel-inner{ :role => "listbox"}
                - @images.each do |image|
                    .item
                        %img{ :src => "car-images/#{image}"}
            %a.left.carousel-control{ "data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#myCarousel", :role => "button"}
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left{ "aria-hidden" => "true"}
                %span.sr-only Previous
            %a.right.carousel-control{ "data-slide" => "next", :href => "#myCarousel", :role => "button"}
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right{ "aria-hidden" => "true"}
                %span.sr-only Next
```

And this is how it renders in a browser:

```
<div class='col-sm-6' id='carousel'>
      <div class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' id='myCarousel' style='height:inherit'>
        <ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>
        <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_1.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_2.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_3.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_4.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_5.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_6.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_7.jpg'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img src='car-images/fb_8.jpg'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class='left carousel-control' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel' role='button'>
          <span aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
          <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel' role='button'>
          <span aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
          <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also, the Ruby code that runs the view:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

$car_img_dir = 'public/car-images'

get '/' do
    @images = Dir.foreach($car_img_dir).select { |x| File.file?("#  {$car_img_dir}/#{x}") }
    haml :index
end
get '/about' do
    haml :about
end 

get '/products' do
    haml :products
end
```

I have been trying to solve this for about 2.5 hours now, and being a beginner, I am unaware of any solutions.

Comment: You're using global variables `$car_img_dir`. Don't do that until you understand when and why you should use a global. Instead, learn about variable scope and the use of constants.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a global is bad practice. I'd recommend learning about variable scoping and using constants. Eventually you'll learn why and when to use a global but until them it'd be better to avoid them.

The code in question could be written more idiomatically like:

```
CAR_IMG_DIR = 'public/car-images'

get '/' do
  @images = Dir.foreach(CAR_IMG_DIR).select { |x| File.file?(File.join(CAR_IMG_DIR, x)) }
  haml :index
end
```

Rather than assume that the path separator character is `/` you should let Ruby determine what it is and supply it. Using `File.join` allows Ruby to do that. See the beginning of the documentation for the [IO class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html) and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-join).

You can't trust the HTML that the browser shows you. Browsers can, and will, modify HTML. You can use `curl` or `wget`, or various HTTP clients for Ruby, or even HAML itself, to view the emitted HTML without the browser getting in the way. I'd recommend getting used to doing that; You always need to know how the browser will render the page, but just don't trust its rendered HTML to be an accurate rendition of the real HTML.

Regarding the image size of 0x0: You can change your template to set the size, or you can add CSS to do it for all images of that class. I'd add the CSS, but you're going to have to do it one place or another. By default the browser should show the images in their native sizes so something is telling the browser to set it to 0x0 and you need to override it. Perhaps looking at the style attributes of the images will give you an idea where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the code "optimization", I will read up on the variable types and usage cases. However even changing the inline style or external css to explicit sizes of height a width did not change the image size from 0*0.

Comment: I am seriously completely lost, even using the image as a backround of its containers did not work even with fixed sizing.